# Cannot run Java from the Windows PowerShell command prompt

Tags: powershell, java

I have Java installed on my machine (the JRE is under `C:\Program Files\Java`) but I can't run any java command from the Windows PowerShell command prompt.

```
>>> java -version
java : The term 'java' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check
the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ java
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (java:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

However, I have noticed that Java does work and that I *can* run Java commands on the old Windows command prompt. Turns out it's only PowerShell where I can't run those commands.

I have JRE 7 and I'm using Windows PowerShell on Windows 8.

Comment: Have you set `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` in `PATH`?

Comment: You need to add Java to your system path.

Answer (score 13):

Make 2 environment variable changes:

1. Add a `JAVA_HOME` variable equal to something like:  `C:\Java\JDK1.7.0_25_x64`
2. Add `%JAVA_HOME%\bin` to the beginning of your `PATH` variable.

Then, start a brand new shell to see if the changes were applied.

Comment: thanks, for others, do not miss step 2 where bin is important. It worked

Answer (score 6):

- In the run dialog box, enter <kbd>sysdm.cpl</kbd>
- In the window that came up, navigate to <kbd>Advanced</kbd> tab. Click on the <kbd>Environment Variables</kbd> button.
- Add the location of your java installation (the bin directory) to the <kbd>PATH</kbd> variable.

  ```
  ;%ProgramFiles%/Java/jre%version%/bin
  ```

  followed by a `;`

Note:

```
%version% means the java version.
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to modify your "PATH" environment variable to add your "java" bin location, one way
via command prompt
`set path=%path%;<your java bin location>;`

But this will be set only for your current session of your terminal.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the Java class path:

Reference:

[How to set class path?](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html)

Or:

[Link-2: How to set class path?](http://www.roseindia.net/java/java-classpath.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

Add it to `C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin` added to the classpath environment variable.

Comment: Thanks.  I needed back slashes for my Windows 10 system. Also the path for me was a little different due to the time that has passed since your post.

Comment: sure that you need the `/bin` folder and not `/lib`? [Reference Link](https://www.roseindia.net/java/java-classpath.shtml)

Answer (score 1):

If the environment variable is set or you have sourced the environment appropriately, the issue is executing a file in a shell:

```
javac .\HelloWorld.java      //That is a file, so it can be ./

java HelloWorld              //Not the correct file name, so it will not execute, and so must call it as in MSDOS
```

You cannot `.\` on the HelloWorld.class as the Java bytecode must be executed without the extension, `.\` is for file execution.

Answer (score 1):

If it works in cmd, but not in PowerShell, **your JDK path entry might be in quotes**.

As described in an [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48601543/1090166), go to system variables, edit the raw text of *Path* and simply remove the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by reinstalling `Git-2.8.2-64-bit.exe`
and following these instructions! https://learn.adafruit.com/windows-tools-for-the-electrical-engineer/git-plus-command-line-tools

I then added the code mentioned above `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.3\bin`

- by navigating to control panel `/system/Advanced` tab
- Click on "Environment Variables" then "system's variables"
- and looked for `Path` to edited and
- then added `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.3\bin`

After that, all is working for me now in a Windows PowerShell and also a MinGW64! See images of it working: [image: Windows power shell]

Comment: Unfortunately, the edit queue seems to be full - Paths are better readable when formatted as code `C:\my_example\path`

Answer (score 0):

If it works in the regular shell but not in PowerShell, maybe you had PowerShell open when you installed or set your path and you just need to close PowerShell and reopen a new one to pick up the new path.

Answer (score 0):

If this occurs while running the script, edit the value for JAVA_HOME inside script.

example:
`[string] $java_home = "C:\env\java\jdk-1.8.0.222",`

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had to restart my terminal, it worked after that.

I hope this helps to anyone with my same issue