# I keep getting an error whenever I have tried to start up lavalink

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I downloaded lavalink in the same folder that I have my project and I have the application.yml code all correct. I still keep getting the error of

```
java : The term 'java' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or 
if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ java -jar Lavalink.jar
+ ~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (java:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

If you guys need to see any other pieces of code I would happily show you.

I tried downloading the latest version of Java from Oracle. I have put the two files in the same project folder. I have matched the ports in both my main project folder and the application folder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cannot run Java from the Windows PowerShell command prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16811332/cannot-run-java-from-the-windows-powershell-command-prompt)

Comment: i fixed this issue already